# Triggering a context menu click in Microstrategy + Javascript

Tags: javascript, microstrategy

I am currently working in Microstrategy which is a BI tool platform and I am trying to do an automatic click from a context menu.  For some reason I am not able to trigger the click automatically with the code.  I was hoping I can get assistance to figure out the value of "this" that way I can pass it through.  The ultimate goal is to pass any of the grid_K47 to be remove and the page refresh.  Below on the click of the menuClick in real life force the page to refresh which is what I want it to do.

Here is what I know.

The object before the right click is in the table and display this.  Please keep in mind that this is all MSTR rendered code.

This is the spot that I right click on

```
<td id="grid_K47_0_1_1_1" class="c4_K47" dpt="1" dg="TRUE" ds="Area" oid="4216C7074826CF50BC81B8BDEFB99603" style="cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.5;" frmid="CCFBE2A5EADB4F50941FB879CCF1721C" title="Area. Drag object to perform pivot. Right-click for more options" frmlist="ID45C11FA478E745FEA08D781CEA190FE520DESCCCFBE2A5EADB4F50941FB879CCF1721C1-1" or="V" sty="ATT" fe="h1;4216C7074826CF50BC81B8BDEFB99603;UK & Ireland" ax="1" frmname="DESC" oty="12" mx="1" cx="[11,15,16,17,18,19,20,4,26,4,4,29,30,31,32,33,36,37,38]">Area</td>
```

Then the context menu pulls up and has this section

```
<tr id="cm1r10" height="18" style="cursor: pointer;" li="var bone = microstrategy.findBone(microstrategy.activeCXMenu); bone.processContextMenus('x');;" onclick="menuClick(this, 'grid_K47_0_GM1');" onmouseout="menuOff(this);" onmouseover="clearTimeout(oSubCTimer); menuOn(this); hideContextSubMenus(1);" ac="true" class="menu-row">
```

So far I have tested different value for "this" that is in the menuclick function.  Here is my latest

HTML

```
<div style="background-color:#E1E1E1;"> <input type="button" name="RemoveGrid"  id="RemoveGrid" value="Submit" ></div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#RemoveGrid").on("click", function (e) {

RemoveGridjs();

});
});
</script>
<script>
function RemoveGridjs() {
var bone = microstrategy.findBone(microstrategy.activeCXMenu); 
bone.processContextMenus('x');;
menuClick('#grid_K47_0_1_1_1', 'grid_K47_0_GM1');
}
</script>
```

Comment: why do you need to remove from the grid an attribute at runtime? any specific reason? maybe you can do this in a different way

Comment: The business want to be able to do real time grid editing.

the scenario is let say you have a grid with Market and City.  But they want to replace Market with State.  The expectation is to be able to use a drop down to select state another for City and hit a submit button in a dashboard view.

Comment: I think that something like this could be done more effectively using Java or .Net SDK. I saw something similar once and it was done with Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some JavaScript customization for MicroStrategy and it was quite a nightmare to figure out how to do things. MicroStrategy, as company, doesn't support JavaScript customization, so there is no documentation for it, also online there is not much you can find.

I'm not sure which version of MicroStrategy and which visualization you are using (interactive works differently from express mode), anyway my suggestion is to modify the onclick to log `this` so that you can have an idea about this object is that.

Something like that:

```
jQuery('#cm1r10').click(
  function(){
              console.log(this)
  }
);
```

Another way to tackle the problem is not to try to run the function associated to the menu item, but to simulate the button click on it.

```
jQuery("#RemoveGrid").on("click", 
                         function (e) {
                                jQuery('#cm1r10').trigger('click');
                         }
);
```

Not sure if this works if the context menu is not showing on the screen, but I think it's worth a try.

Anyway I suggest you to use `jQuery` instead of `$` when you are customizing someone else code

Comment: So when I am trying to do the console log but it is only giving the error of Use of attributes' nodeValue attribute is deprecated. Use value instead.  It is not writing back the log.  If I were to console log on the right click to bring up the context menu how would I do that for right click.

Comment: I was able to do a console log on the right click
jQuery(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        console.log('hello world')
 console.log(this)
    });

but I got a url  Not necessary an item

Comment: I did a bit of digging. I create a function `MenuClickOld = MenuClick` and then `function menuClick(oMenuItem,sMenu) {console.log(oMenuItem); console.log(sMenu); menuClickOld(oMenuItem,sMenu)}`. This replace the old version with a new one, then I was able to call menu click (`menuClickOld($('#cm1r10')[0], 'grid_K48_0_GM1')`), but this works only if the context menu is there. I went digging further it become quite messy...

Comment: I am not understanding where to put the menuclickold = menuclick  I have this


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
       
menuClickOld(jQuery('#cmlr10')[0], 'grid_K47_0_GM1');
});

});



function menuClick(oMenuItem,sMenu) {
console.log(oMenuItem);
console.log(sMenu);
menuClickOld(oMenuItem,sMenu);
}


</script>

Comment: I was putting this in the console, to see which functions were called. Anyway now that I know a bit better the scenario I suggest you to go for an SDK customization